# jquery not getting result from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why I am not getting values from inputs? I checked it with alert box and there's no values. I do not see any wrong codes or maybe i might have forgotten something to write on my code

```
<div class="login" align="left">
                        <input type="input" class="user" placeholder="Username"/>
                        <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                        <button name="login" class="btnLogin" id="btnLogin">LOGIN</button>
                        <div class="register"><a href="register.php" class="reg">Register Now!</a></div>
                    </div>



    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).on('click','#btnLogin',function(){

        var username = $('.user').text();
        var password = $('.pass').text();
        alert(username); //------------>this alert box is null
        $.ajax ({
            url:"login_func.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{username:username, password:password},  
            dataType:"text", 
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: instead of text ...use val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your input type to `text` for username and use `val()` instead `text()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).on('click','#btnLogin',function(){

        var username = $('.user').val(); //here you need to use val()
        var password = $('.pass').val(); //here you need to use val()
        alert(username+ ", "+ password); //------------>this alert box is null
        $.ajax ({
            url:"login_func.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{username:username, password:password},  
            dataType:"text", 
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login" align="left">
    <input type="text" class="user" placeholder="Username"/> <!--here you need to add type text-->
    <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
    <button name="login" class="btnLogin" id="btnLogin">LOGIN</button>
    <div class="register"><a href="register.php" class="reg">Register Now!</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `val()`  and not `text()`

`$('.user').val();`

For all kind of `input` elements , `select` and `textarea` you use `val()` to get its value. And rest elements you use `text()` to get the inner text of those elements

Answer (score 1):

Value from input fields are normally accessed through `.val`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#btnLogin',function(){

        var username = $('.user').val();
        var password = $('.pass').val();
        alert(username); //------------>this alert box is null
        $.ajax ({
            url:"login_func.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{username:username, password:password},  
            dataType:"text", 
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` since you are trying to get a valuye of the input field. `.text()` should be used for a text element like  `<div>`, `<p>` etc.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body><div class="login" align="left">
                        <input type="input" class="user" placeholder="Username"/>
                        <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                        <button name="login" class="btnLogin" id="btnLogin">LOGIN</button>
                        <div class="register"><a href="register.php" class="reg">Register Now!</a></div>
                    </div>



    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).on('click','#btnLogin',function(){

        var username = $('.user').val();
        var password = $('.pass').val();
        alert(username); //------------>this alert box is null
        $.ajax ({
            url:"login_func.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{username:username, password:password},  
            dataType:"text", 
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Input does not have to be retrieved by text but by val().

check this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(document).on('click', '#btnLogin', function() {

    var username = $('.user').val();
    var password = $('.pass').val();
   
    alert(username); //------------>this alert box is null
    $.ajax({
      url: "login_func.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login" align="left">
  <input type="input" class="user" placeholder="Username" />
  <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder="Password" />
  <button name="login" class="btnLogin" id="btnLogin">LOGIN</button>
  <div class="register"><a href="register.php" class="reg">Register Now!</a>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
</script>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()` instead of `.text()` to retrieve values.
and change the input type of user from `input` to `text`.i.e.
`<input type="text" class="user" placeholder="Username"/>`